# How to print (pdf) separate files using direct mail on microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, mail-merge

I'm trying to print / export using direct mail on microsoft word 2016, however I just can not export each pages to a pdf file separated. Is there any way to print / export files using direct mail on microsoft word? Preferential using some `Merge Field` as file name?
[image]

Comment: Use the Edit button to add information to your question. Do not just post comments with the information.

Comment: Are you trying to export each page to a different PDF document and using a data field as the filename? I see you have Acrobat Pro installed, but have you tried using Word's built-in PDF creation capability?

Comment: @music2myear for the first question, YES. For the second one, YES, and there's no this capability.

Comment: Right now I assume you're getting a file save prompt for each and every merged document?

Comment: @music2myear yes, I can do that sending via e-mail, but I want to keep the files instead send.